# Java Inheritance Issues

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a parent class called 'Shape' which has a subclass 'Circle'. The Circle class inherits the properties of Shape and has an additional parameter 'radius', together with a method called getRadius().

Finally I have a 'ShapeList' class that contains an ArrayList of different shapes, together with a variety of add/remove functions.

I am trying to print the Radius of a circle:

```
System.out.println(shapeArray.getShape(1).getRadius());
```

The shapeArray is the list of shapes, and getShape returns a specific shape object. However when I try to use getRadius, it looks at the Shape class rather than the specific Circle subclass and therefore does not recognise the method, how can I access the radius?

Comment: You should *cast* the `Shape`. See [**"Inheritance (The Java Tutorials)"**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for more details.

Comment: It's because it knows only about Shape, not Circle.

Comment: Everyone is saying you should cast. Whilst technically correct, I would take a step back and ask why a list of generic shapes should be aware specifically about radii

Comment: Brian has a very good point... That's the overriding a method bit I referred to below...

Comment: This is a solved problem with a compile-time correct solution. Casting and reflection based solutions are ridiculous. Overriding a method is silly - it pollutes the signature of `Shape` and ends up creating an interface that has so many odd warts on it that it doesn't make any sense. This is the exact case for the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast to Circle before printing. You have to be aware that this may result in a java.lang.ClassCastException!

Simple example:

```
class Shape {
   private String property;
}
class Circle extends Shape {
    private int radius;
    public Circle(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }        

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    public int getRadius() {
        return this.radius;
    }
}


class ShapeArray {
    public ArrayList<Shape> shapeArray = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    public void addShapeToArray(Shape shape){
        shapeArray.add(shape);
    }
    public Shape getShape(int index) {
        return (Shape) this.shapeArray.get(index);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShapeArray shapeArray = new ShapeArray();
        shapeArray.addShapeToArray(new Shape());
        shapeArray.addShapeToArray(new Circle(2));
        System.out.println(shapeArray.getShape(0).getRadius());
    }
}
```

This code will not compile, the line

```
 System.out.println(shapeArray.getShape(0).getRadius());
```

is the problem.
You first need to cast to Circle, like so:

```
 System.out.println(((Circle) shapeArray.getShape(0)).getRadius());
```

However as I wrote in the beginning - this may produce a ClassCastException. So you need to somehow make sure that the object you get is actually a Circle, so that when you cast it - the code will not blow up.

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast your Shape in a Circle:

```
Circle circle = (Circle) shapeArray.getShape(1);
System.out.println(circle.getRadius());
```

Of course, this sort of invalidate the whole meaning of having a parent class.

Comment: Also add an instanceof check as other shapes might be there as well

Comment: Was'nt on the original sample, so I assumed it to be done "somewhere else". You are of course right, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(((Circle)shapeArray.getShape(1)).getRadius());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should *cast* `Shape` object to `Circle`.

Note that when you *explicitly* cast an object, you're telling the compiler to trust you that you know what you're doing, and you're *sure* that the `Shape` **is** a `Circle`. If that's not the case, you might get a *runtime exception*. In order to avoid that, use `instanceof` operator.

I highly recommend you to read [**"Inheritance (The Java Tutorials)"**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Answer (score 0):

Printing the radius means you know that your particular `Shape` is a `Circle`.

If you want your program to know this too, you can tell it **via a cast**:

```
Circle circle = (Circle) shapeArray.getShape(1);
```

Now the program knows that `circle` is indeed a `Circle`, and you may use `getRadius()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast to a Circle.

Google for Java + Casting...

What you're doing though seems a bit confused - I would be tempted to keep separate arrays for each type of shape, meaning you can run some code for the circles (like say getRadius), together with other specfiic code for polygons (say printing out the vertices...)

You could also override a "GetDetails" method on the shape class, allowing you to maintain a single array as you currently have, but have each object on it return information relevant to it's type of shape...

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers thus far are defeating the purpose of using the type system in Java.

Understand and use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Think about what you have created:

- A `Circle`, that "is a" `Shape`
- An container which can hold anything that "is a" `Shape`

This does not mean that everything in the container is a `Circle`.

How do you expect your program to behave when someone places something that is not a `Circle` in your container?

Casting and using instanceof are hacks that suggest a poorly designed program/system.